# es lint --fix only supresses the error and doesnt fix

Tags: vuejs2, eslint, lint, prettier

Trying to solve linting issues installed npm eslint in vs code editor ,then tried eslint --fix but 
es lint --fix only supresses the error and doesnt fix it completely,is there any npm command or a way to  fix `all the linting errors ,apart from doing it manually`

Answer (score 2):

can use `npm run lint` or `npm run lint --fix` for fixing lint errors in the code.
you will get the errors found in the code and errors fixed by lint fix.